# Css background video

Tags: html, css, video, background

Does someone know how to center this video background?

I tried:

```
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
```

So far but none of these worked.

This is my code.

Html:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="vid">
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Css:

```
video#vid {
 position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
 min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
 width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
 background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

How do i center this video background so it removes on the left/right side the same amount if you resize the window? Thanks for helping!

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwxcvxe8/2/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you are using an `HTML5` element the best way to center content is to put it in a relative container and then let CSS handle the rest like this:

```
<div id="Container">
    <video></video>
    <div></div>
</div>

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#Container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Container video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    /* The following will size the video to fit the full container. Not necessary, just nice.*/
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 0;
}

#Container div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You can replace `<video>` by any element you want to center, of course. Because you are using the `video` element I'm ignoring older browsers as I guess they won't like your page anyway. You also don't *have to* use the `min-` values, and it would just center.

Comment: You have to set your `body, html` height as `100%`, or give the container a fixed height (say `400px`); Otherwise the `#container` will have a height of 0, making the `top: 50%` half of 0... which is 0. Then it moves it `-50%` in the translate. I amended my post.

Comment: @tomer Just want to mention that, since I read this just now, the only change i'd make it the positioning using `calc`: `top: 0; left: 0; top: calc(50%); left: calc(50%);`. Older browsers that don't support `calc` (IE8 and lower) also don't support `transform` and will therefore just display the element without moving it (it crops differently but it's a nice fallback). This makes no difference for `video` elements as IE8 does not support them anyway, but if you're centring an image it's an easy way to ensure compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Working example with `object-fit: cover;` More about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.videobg {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; /* requires for to position video properly */
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  object-fit: cover; /* combined with 'absolute', works like background-size, but for DOM elements */
}
```

```html
<div class="videobg">
  <video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit), you can manipulate [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and do this without the container.

```
video.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   .name-class {
    background: url(../images/tv-temp.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 686px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
    }
    .name-class video {
    height: 473px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 148px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    }
<div class="name-class">
<video controls playsinline="" loop="" autoplay="">
<source src="..\video-name.mp4" type="video/mp4" autostart="true">

</video>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value

Answer (score 0):

place the video inside a `<center>` tag

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated and should not be used.