# Lighbox bootstrap img-responsive not working in FireFox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, lightbox

I have a gallery using Lighbox in a static html bootstrap site.
It works fine in Chrome, Safari etc but not FireFox.
The img-responsive function doent seem to work on the thumbnails.
Any help gratfully received.

[Here is a link to the site](http://jhurleydesign.com/vixencnc/gallery.html)

Comment: You should post the relevant code in your question and not make people go to your website (since it seems that you are working on it) With that said in Firefox the lightbox worked fine for me (maybe because you are working on it?) but the page layout is really messed up. One thing that may help is making your video display as a background. See this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905511/css-background-video

Answer (score 1):

You should assing the "col" classes to the immediate parent of the images to see the img-responsive class working. 
Since the img-responsive class sets the image width to the width of the parent, you need to have an element with a set width to have contain the image. To ensure responsiveness, the width you set on the parent should be a percentage.
 you can get rid of the various `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">` and add those classes to the contained `<a>` tags, like so:

```
<a class="example-image-link col-md-3 col-sm-6" data-title="Selection of various components made at Vixen" data-lightbox="example-set" href="images/components-01.jpg">
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

make your a's block:

```
a.example-image-link {display: block; }
```