# HTML website video background

Tags: html

For html coding how is a video inserted in a website background like this example: http://www.buildingengines.com/. I just need a step in the right direction.

Comment: It is possible that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905511/css-background-video) contains some good information about video elements.

Answer (score 0):

Place video with lower z-index as the content then position content accordingly.

```css
video {
z-index: 0;
}
h1 {
z-index: 2;
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<video width="400" autoplay>
  <source  src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<h1>Text</h1>
```

Comment: Note that `z-index` only works when the element it's applied to is a positioned element (i.e. anything but `position: static`, which is the default value.)